# Pandas: minute based column, need to add 15 seconds at each row

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
1      2019-04-22 00:01:00
2      2019-04-22 00:01:00
3      2019-04-22 00:01:00
4      2019-04-22 00:01:00
5      2019-04-22 00:02:00
6      2019-04-22 00:02:00
7      2019-04-22 00:02:00
8      2019-04-22 00:02:00
9      2019-04-22 00:03:00
10     2019-04-22 00:03:00
11     2019-04-22 00:03:00
12     2019-04-22 00:03:00
```

As you can see there are four rows for each minute, what I would need is to add 15 secondes to each row so that it looks like this:

```
1      2019-04-22 00:01:00
2      2019-04-22 00:01:15
3      2019-04-22 00:01:30
4      2019-04-22 00:01:45
5      2019-04-22 00:02:00
6      2019-04-22 00:02:15
7      2019-04-22 00:02:30
8      2019-04-22 00:02:45
9      2019-04-22 00:03:00
10     2019-04-22 00:03:15
11     2019-04-22 00:03:30
12     2019-04-22 00:03:45
```

Any idea on how to proceed? I am not really good at datetime object so I am a bit stuck on that one... thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add timedeltas to datetimes column:

```
df['date'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('date').cumcount() * 15, unit='s')

print (df)
                  date
1  2019-04-22 00:01:00
2  2019-04-22 00:01:15
3  2019-04-22 00:01:30
4  2019-04-22 00:01:45
5  2019-04-22 00:02:00
6  2019-04-22 00:02:15
7  2019-04-22 00:02:30
8  2019-04-22 00:02:45
9  2019-04-22 00:03:00
10 2019-04-22 00:03:15
11 2019-04-22 00:03:30
12 2019-04-22 00:03:45
```

**Detail**:

First create counter `Series` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df.groupby('date').cumcount())
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     0
6     1
7     2
8     3
9     0
10    1
11    2
12    3
dtype: int64
```

Multiple by `15` and convert to seconds timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('date').cumcount() * 15, unit='s'))
1    00:00:00
2    00:00:15
3    00:00:30
4    00:00:45
5    00:00:00
6    00:00:15
7    00:00:30
8    00:00:45
9    00:00:00
10   00:00:15
11   00:00:30
12   00:00:45
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```